# google.accounts.id.prompt stopped working

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I have a custom button for signing in with Google and I am triggering google.accounts.id.prompt with a JS onclick event. I have noticed that first there is a call to https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status?client_id=XXX and then the popup shows up.

But since a few days ago the popup stopped showing up and I am seeing that the call to https://accounts.google.com/gsi/status?client_id=XXX is returning an invalid format:

)]}'
[["PsJeB0CyFkGlqPMw88i9tA"],null,0]

(Content-Type response header is application/json and that is clearly not valid JSON)

Does anyone know what's going on? This is happening in incognito mode as well.